# how to convert entity diagram (.vpp) to database or text file in java

Tags: java, html, database, erd, visual-paradigm

I want to convert an **entity diagram to a database table or text file** using java code. How can I do it? Can I export the .vpp file to an HTML file and after this convert the HTML file to a text file?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the docs? https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/sdevsgendb.jsp

Comment: i wnat in my program ( java code ) to insert a erd file and convert it with my code the type of this file is .vpp or html doc

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you may consider to use Visual Paradigm's Open API to develop Java plugin (https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/pluginuserguide.jsp) and interact with the model data within the project file. This allow you to retrieve the model data and convert to whatever format you want.